# Canvas draw line with border

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, path-2d

I need to draw a line and give it a border.

I tried to draw two lines, one 5px and above 3px

But that doesn't exactly seem like a real border

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const path = new Path2D();

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

path.moveTo(40, 40);
path.lineTo(50, 35);
path.lineTo(60, 40);

ctx.stroke(path);

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

path.moveTo(40, 40);
path.lineTo(50, 35);
path.lineTo(60, 40);

ctx.stroke(path);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Is there a better way to draw a border for a line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How create a line with borders in HTML5 canvas properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874375/how-create-a-line-with-borders-in-html5-canvas-properly)

Comment: @Taxel No. I saw this answer before. 
maybe the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441610/double-line-stroke-in-html5-canvas/13442548#13442548) in the answer is the way to do it.
But I didn't succeed to do it

Comment: Try adding `ctx.lineCap="square"` for the wider line and `ctx.lineCap="butt"` for the other one

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "endCap" on the outer line:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const path = new Path2D();

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineCap = "butt"; // butt  round  square <-- other options

path.moveTo(40, 40);
path.lineTo(50, 35);
path.lineTo(60, 40);

ctx.stroke(path);

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

path.moveTo(40, 40);
path.lineTo(50, 35);
path.lineTo(60, 40);

ctx.stroke(path);
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap

Answer (score 0):

You could try with shadow:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawPath(path) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.shadowColor = 'black';

  for (i = 0; i <= 360; i += 10) {
    a = i * Math.PI / 180
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4 * Math.sin(a)
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4 * Math.cos(a)
    ctx.stroke(path);
  }
}

const path = new Path2D();
path.moveTo(20, 40);
path.lineTo(50, 35);
path.lineTo(80, 40);
path.lineTo(80, 80);
path.lineTo(160, 80);
drawPath(path);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=200 height=100></canvas>
```

The idea is to draw with a slightly different offset all-around your path object   ... and that same logic can be used for images:

https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvasOutline.html